# How to get unique rows with condition in r?

Tags: r, unique

I have a data frame like below.

```
d1:
user  time1   time2   time3
u1    07:00   07:15   07:20
u1    07:10   07:30   07:55
u2    07:20   08:00   08:10
u3    07:30   08:05   08:20
```

If time(time column is from another data frame) is **07:45**.I have to get unique user rows with condition `time3 > time`. d1 data frame changes w.r.t time column from another data frame.In new data frame i have to get **unique users** with no repetition.

```
I have tried like below:
for(i in 1:nrow(d1)){
  if(d1$user[i] != d1$user[i+1]){
    d2 <- d1[which(d1$time3 > "07:45"),]
}
}
```

I am getting error when it comes to last row because of the if condition.But , `I have to check if any user repeated in the user column and with condition time3>time`.

```
Expected output :

user  time1   time2   time3
u1    07:10   07:30   07:55
u2    07:20   08:00   08:10
u3    07:30   08:05   08:20
```

I know my condition is wrong but i am not getting any idea on how to achieve the above output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(lubridate) # for hm function to compare times

last_unique <- length(d1$user)-match(unique(d1$user),rev(d1$user))+1
```

```r
rows <- which(last_unique == which(hm(d1$time3) > hm("07:45")))
```

Get the rows where the last unique value is also greater than 07:45

```r
d2 <- d1[last_unique[rows],]
```

Subset unique user and time greater than 07:45

For the case where you want to select the most recent unique value *earlier* than a specified time, simply reverse the logic:

```r
d1 <- read.table(text = "
user,time1,time2,time3
u1,07:05,07:10,07:25
u1,07:20,07:30,07:40
u2,07:20,08:00,08:10
u3,07:30,08:05,08:20
u4,07:10,07:15,07:20
u4,07:25,07:30,07:35", sep = ',', header = TRUE)

rows <- which(hm(d1$time3) < hm("07:45")) 
temp <- d1[rows,]
last_unique <- length(temp$user)-match(unique(temp$user),rev(temp$user))+1

d2 <- temp[last_unique,]
d2
  user time1 time2 time3
2   u1 07:20 07:30 07:40
6   u4 07:25 07:30 07:35
```

Comment: And I have a another senario also. if user name repeated twice and time 3 which are less than "07:45". I should pick latest time row .How to do that?

Comment: Example:  ```u1 07:05 07:10 07:25 ``` ,``` u1 07:20 07:30 07:40```, I should extract the second row.

Comment: But it should check for user if the first row user is same as the second row user i should get latest time row w.r.t time column.Here , time column value is 07:45

Comment: Match returns the first match of each unique user. To get the last match, get the number of users with ````length````, then match the unique users with the reversed order of users. So in reverse order, the first match of ````u1```` is the 3rd position, the last in in 4th position. Subtracting this from the number of users and adding one reorders back from the reversed order. Which gives the index of the last unique user.

Comment: Everything else is the same just change the condition to less than ````rows <- which(latest_unique == which(hm(d1$time3) < hm("07:40")))````

Comment: Yes,I have tried with ```rows <- which(latest_unique == which(hm(d1$time3) < hm("07:45"))) ``` .It returning zero rows even though time3 < "07:45"

Answer (score 0):

And if you try something like this:

```
d1$test <- c(diff(d1$user, lag = 1), NA)
d2 <- d1[d1$test == 0 & d1$time3 > "07:45", ]
```

What I suggested was to create a new column to test if each user is equal the next, and keep in d2 just the users repeated and with time > tham 07:45.

Hope it helps you!